# Merging multiple word documents (with images) in Java

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to create a simple utility application but have issues with merging two word documents with images.

Pls find my below code (i am using Apache POI). The code works fine for Text and other information but fails to merge documents with Images.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;

public class WordMerge {
    private final OutputStream result;
    private final List<InputStream> inputs;
    private XWPFDocument first;

    public WordMerge(OutputStream result) {
        this.result = result;
        inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(InputStream stream) throws Exception{            
        inputs.add(stream);
        OPCPackage srcPackage = OPCPackage.open(stream);
        XWPFDocument src1Document = new XWPFDocument(srcPackage);         
        if(inputs.size() == 1){
            first = src1Document;
        } else {            
            CTBody srcBody = src1Document.getDocument().getBody();
            first.getDocument().addNewBody().set(srcBody);            
        }        
    }

    public void doMerge() throws Exception{
        first.write(result);                
    }

    public void close() throws Exception{
        result.flush();
        result.close();
        for (InputStream input : inputs) {
            input.close();
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream faos = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/result.docx");
        WordMerge wm = new WordMerge(faos);
        wm.add( new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\test.docx") );
        wm.add( new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\word_images.docx") );
        wm.doMerge();
        wm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "The code works fine for Text and other information": No, it does not. Simply appending multiple document bodys one after the other is not the same as merging `Word` documents. Merging `Word` documents is a very complex process because of the complexity of `Word`'s file format. Images for example are stored in a separate part of the `Word` filesystem and only referenced in document's body by Id. So those separate parts also would must be merged and the Ids would must be corrected. Same for comments, header, footer, numberings, ...